# Как отправить GET-запрос через PHP?

Tags: php, get

По данному адресу
`http://smsc.ru/sys/send.php?login=<login>&psw=<password>&phones=<phones>&mes=<message>`
нужно отправить GET-запрос.
Как это можно реализовать через PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как это можно реализовать через PHP?

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/sys/send.php?login=&psw=&phones=&mes=");
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью модуля curl, он позволяет формировать запрос с учётом куков и остальных хедеров http, очень удобен в использовании, и довольно гибок. С помощью этого модуля можно не только get запрос производить